# Screen resolution and scrolling bar issue

Tags: css

in chrome, when the screen resolution(full screen) is maximum i want scroll bar function disabled. When the screen resolution is reduced (Minimized) i want my scroll bar function to be working. is it possible if so how?

```
.content {
 margin: 1vmin;
 padding: 12px;
 margin-top:23%;
 background-color: blue;
 height: 1000px;
```

}

i was using the above css code. for minimized page height is ok but when in full screen there is unnecessary scroll. i want to remove it.

Comment: Did you try something? If yes, please show your code.

Comment: edited the content pls check

Answer (score 0):

The is pretty simple, if your content's width is more than the viewport width, it will either be scrollable or hidden partially, based on the css you write. I suppose you don't want to hide you content on any screen, but you want it to be scrollable on mobile devices for better view.
First thing you should do for responsiveness is this tag:

```sh
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This will set your content width as per the viewport and then you can use your own css or any library like bootstrap to make it responsive/scrollable in mobiles.For example, Bootstrap's `.table-responsive` class is good to make responsive tables are easy to slide and view on mobiles rather than shrink to fit.

Comment: no! not in other devices. i want this only on desktop in minimized form to work

Comment: For a web application. there is not much difference between a mobile and a screen minimized to mobile size(in terms of css). Try this and it will be ok.

Comment: thank you i am a begginer can u help me whereto give the above code?

Comment: anywhere between the <head> </head> section.

Comment: this didn't solve my issue :( this code is already given before itself

Comment: You need to use media queries or some responsive design frameworks for changing the styles on different sizes. It will not work just by adding this line of  code.